# Service Console - update tab's pageInfo after redirect

Tags: javascript, console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

Suppose I have page `PageA` opened in a Salesforce Classic console tab. Then I use a controller method to redirect to `PageB`:

```
public PageReference redirect(){
    return new PageReference('/apex/PageB');
}
```

And the page displayed in the tab changes correctly. But when I call salesforceIntegration JS method `sforce.console.getPageInfo()` on that tab it still returns the previous URL: `{ success: true, pageInfo: "{"url":"https://sfdc.visual.force.com/apex/PageA"}" }`

Is there any way to make it return the current URL or any other way to check if a given tab actually displays `PageB`?

Comment: Have you tried setting redirect as `true`? Ex: `Pagereference pf = new PageReference('/apex/PageB'); pf.setRedirect(true);`

Comment: @manjit_singh Unfortunately, it doesn't work.